# How to count the number of created records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my controller:

```
def import
  Model.import(params[:file]) if params[:file]
  Model.create(model_params) if params[:model]
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Things imported."
end
```

I would like to be able to show a notice saying "4 things imported." for example. But I don't know how to extract the inserted records count from the operation.

Is there a built-in way to find this out that is database agnostic?

Comment: Can you post the import method please.  Essentially you'd implement a counter there.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I'll post the code shortly

Comment: Isn't that [`activerecord-import`](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) by chance? UPD: I guess not, arguments don't seem to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
# app/models/mymodel.rb
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.import(csv_file)
    create_count = 0

    CSV.foreach(csv_file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Model.create! row.to_hash
      create_count += 1
    end

    return create_count
  end
end

# app/controllers/mycontroller.rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def import
    begin
      created_count = MyModel.import(params[:file])
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "#{created_count} things imported."
    rescue
      redirect_to root_url, error: "Couldn't import CSV file, nothing imported."
    end
  end
end
```

Another implementation that would also probably work:

```
# app/controllers/mycontroller.rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def import
    begin
      before_count = MyModel.count
      MyModel.import(params[:file])
      after_count = MyModel.count
      added_count = before_count - after_count
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "#{added_count} things imported."
    rescue
      redirect_to root_url, error: "Couldn't import CSV file, nothing imported."
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods you can use: [`size` and `count`](http://web.archive.org/web/20100210204319/http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size)

- [`Size`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationCollection/size) is for when you *haven't* loaded any SQL data into an ActiveRecord Object
- [`Count`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/count) is for when you *have* loaded SQL data into an object

You could therefore call:

```
Model.count
```

... to get the number of records in the model

Comment: That would return the total number of records in the model, not the number of records just added.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 3 methods for obtaining this information: `length`, `count`, and `size`

**collection.count**

- Counts number of elements using an SQL query (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...)
- `count` results are not stored in memory. This means, every time you call this methis it will file a new query!

  ```
  collection = Record.all.count  #> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `records`
  ```

**collection.length**

- Returns the length of a collection from memory if loaded eagerly
- The collection must be in memory for this to work

  ```
  collection = Record.all.length  #> Record Load (122.9ms)  SELECT `records`.* FROM `records`
  ```

**collection.size**

- This is a Rails method
- This method combines both methods above (`count` and `length`)
- If the collection is in memory, it will get the length
- If the collection is not in memory, it will run an SQL query and `count` it

  ```
  collection = Record.all
  collection.count  # > SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `records`
  collection.count  # > SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `records`
  collection.size   # > SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `records`
  collection.to_a.size  # > Record Load SELECT `records`.* FROM `records`
  ```

Comment: That would return the total number of records, I was looking for the number of added records only.

Comment: Aha, thanks for the clarification.  I'll leave this here in case someone stumbles on it.